# expire or redirect http of 401 for mod_auth_openidc

Tags: apache, http-status-code-401, openid-connect, mod-auth, mod-auth-openidc

I'm not sure if this is something handled in OIDC or apache in general but what I'm seeing is this and was hoping for some advice:

A customer is logged into multiple Google accounts and at the Account Chooser they click the wrong account they get a 401 Unauthorized

They then try to go back to the OIDC server and they continue to get the unauthorized. This is true even if they clear cookies etc.

The only reliable way I can get them to log back in is they open a private window in safari or another personality in Chrome.

Is there a way to have a 401 redirect to the Google Account Chooser and then allow apache to retry? Basically the once they get a 401 from apache - via openidc - there is no good way to reauth again. Is there some way to make retrying login easier for people?

Thanks in advance. My configs are below:

```
<VirtualHost _default_:443>
   ServerName nameofserver.com
   ServerAdmin ops@nameofserver.com
   DocumentRoot /var/www/html
   Header always set Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=63072000; includeSubDomains"
   Header add Set-Cookie "ROUTEID=.%{BALANCER_WORKER_ROUTE}e; path=/" env=BALANCER_ROUTE_CHANGED
   SetEnvIf Origin "^(.*\.nameofserver\.co,)$" ORIGIN_SUB_DOMAIN=$1
   Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "%{ORIGIN_SUB_DOMAIN}e" env=ORIGIN_SUB_DOMAIN
   Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Credentials "true"
   ErrorDocument 503 "A custom error message"
   RequestHeader set X-Forwarded-Proto "https" early
   LimitRequestFieldSize 65000

   SSLEngine on
   SSLCertificateFile /etc/apache2/pathtoprivcert
   SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/apache2/ssl/pathtoprivkey
   SSLProtocol             TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2
   SSLCipherSuite          ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:DHE-DSS-AES128-GCM-SHA256:kEDH+AESGCM:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:DHE-DSS-AES128-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA256:DHE-DSS-AES256-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:!aNULL:!eNULL:!EXPORT:!DES:!RC4:!3DES:!MD5:!PSK
   SSLHonorCipherOrder     on
   SSLCompression          off

   OIDCProviderMetadataURL https://accounts.google.com/.well-known/openid-configuration
   OIDCClientID clientIDfromGoogle@google.com
   OIDCClientSecret Averysecrtkey

   OIDCScope "openid email profile"
   OIDCRedirectURI https://www.nameofserver.com/oauth2callback
   OIDCCryptoPassphrase Alsoverysecurekey

   OIDCSessionInactivityTimeout 86400

   OIDCCookiePath /

   OIDCRemoteUserClaim email
   OIDCAuthNHeader X-Forwarded-User

   LogLevel info


   <Proxy balancer://http-nameofserver>
     BalancerMember http://www1.nameofserver.com route=0
     BalancerMember http://www2.nameofserver.com route=1
     BalancerMember http://www3.nameofserver.com route=2

     ProxySet lbmethod=byrequests
     ProxySet stickysession=ROUTEID
     ProxySet failonstatus=503
     ProxySet maxattempts=2
   </Proxy>

   <Proxy balancer://ws-nameofserver>
     BalancerMember ws://www1.nameofserver.com route=0
     BalancerMember ws://www2.nameofserver.com route=1
     BalancerMember ws://www3.nameofserver.com route=2

     ProxySet lbmethod=byrequests
     ProxySet stickysession=ROUTEID
     ProxySet failonstatus=503
     ProxySet maxattempts=2
   </Proxy>


   RewriteEngine On
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  ^/socket.io            [NC]
   RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} transport=websocket    [NC]
   RewriteRule /(.*) balancer://ws-nameofserver/$1 [P,L]

   ProxyPreserveHost on
   ProxyPass / balancer://http-nameofserver/
   ProxyPassReverse / balancer://http-nameofserver/
   ProxyPass /socket.io/ balancer://ws-nameofserver/socket.io/
   ProxyPassReverse /socket.io/ balancer://ws-nameofserver/socket.io/

   ProxyRequests     Off
   AllowEncodedSlashes NoDecode

      <Location />
         AuthType openid-connect
         Require host somealloweddomain.com
         Require claim hd:corpsite.com
         Require claim hd:someotherdomain.com
         Require claim hd:yetanothercompany.com
      </Location>

      <LocationMatch "^(?!/t/|/an-url|/another-url|/lasturl)/[^/]+">
         OIDCUnAuthAction 401
      </LocationMatch>

</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a custom parameter `prompt=select_account` in the authentication requests as described in:
https://github.com/pingidentity/mod_auth_openidc/wiki#13-how-can-i-add-custom-parameters-to-the-authorization-request

So in your case add:

```
OIDCAuthRequestParams prompt=select_account
```